# append select option if value equal or selected in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 select tags. second is depend on the first one. It is working if I check by only value, but I also need to check if is selected.

```
if(el.val() === "LOCATIONS" || el.is(' option:selected') ){
 $("#status option").remove();
 $("#status").append("<option value=''>All Packages</option><option value=''>KL</option>");
}
```

I'm trying to make depended select dropdown. if I remove `el.is('option:selected')`  it appends the options based on the chosen option of 1st select. but it should also append the options if any option is selected on the first dropdown

here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rQBFZ/303/)

Comment: If you check value then no need to check selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it works even if you check `one condition` i.e. the value of selected option. But to pass two conditions you have to use `&& operator` and instead of `el.is('option:selected')`, you can change this to `("el:selected");` as below,

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
var a = $("#source > option:selected").val();
if(a == "REGIONAL"){
    $("#status option").remove();
        $("#status").append("<option value=''>All Packages</option><option value='Airports'>Airports</option>");
}
$("#source").change(function() {    
    var el = $(this);
    if((el.val() === "AUDIENCES SEGMENT") && ('el:selected')) {
    $("#status option").remove();
    $("#status").append("<option value=''>All Packages</option><option value='Youth'>Youth</option><option value='Working Adults'>Working Adults</option><option value='Family'>Family</option><option value='Travellers'>Travellers</option>");
    }
      else if((el.val() === "REGIONAL") && ('el:selected')) {
        $("#status option").remove();
        $("#status").append("<option value=''>All Packages</option><option value='Airports'>Airports</option>");
        
        }
        
        else if((el.val() === "LOCATIONS") && ('el:selected')) {
        $("#status option").remove();
        $("#status").append("<option value=''>All Packages</option><option value=''>KL</option>");
        
        }
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Source:
  <select id="source" name="source">
     <option>All Types</option>
     <option value="AUDIENCES SEGMENT">AUDIENCES SEGMENT</option>
     <option selected value="REGIONAL">REGIONAL</option>
     <option value="LOCATIONS">LOCATIONS</option>
  </select>

Status:

<select id="status" name="status">
    <option>All Packages</option>
</select>
```

Comment: in the exmaple, REGIONAL is selected but it is not appending `<option value='Airports'>Airports</option>`

Comment: @Elyor onChange it will append that value.

Comment: what can we use instead of onChange? you got the problem right?

Comment: @Elyor Check updated code, declaring a condition before change. Hope it works.

Comment: I'm testing on jsfiddle, it is not showing. maybe I'm missing something

Comment: @Elyor check here on stack above codes it works fine, and jsFiddle link is here http://jsfiddle.net/rQBFZ/305/